# Mod_Rewrite Question

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to forward example.com/signup and example.com/signup/ (with trailing slash) to example.com/signup.php

I wrote following to .htaccess and it works for example.com/signup/ but doesn't work without trailing slash... How can I solve the problem?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^question/(.*)-(.*) /question.php?qid=$1
RewriteRule ^signup/ /signup.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^signup/?$ /signup.php
```

The question mark makes the slash optional, and the dollar sign means end-of-line, so nothing can follow. You can remove the `$` if you like.

You could also allow arbitrary query strings at the end of the URL with something like:

```
RewriteRule ^signup/?(\?.*)?$ /signup.php$1
```

That would allow you to pass any query parameters on to your PHP script. For example the URL `http://www.example.com/signup?destination=/front-page` would be redirected to `http://www.example.com/signup.php?destination=/front-page`.

Answer (score 3):

Make the slash optional with the `?` quantifier:

```
RewriteRule ^signup/?$ /signup.php
```

But I recommend you to just use one notation and redirect the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Put a question mark after the slash

```
RewriteRule ^signup/? /signup.php
```

? = optional single character in regex matches